# Looking for an alternative to document.write for gpt.js file declaration

Tags: javascript, google-dfp, google-publisher-tag

What can I use in place of *document.write* in JavaScript? Is there a different way to rewrite this line of code?

```
document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="' + src + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
```

Comment: Escape `/` at closing `<\/script>` tag. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `createElement` & `appendChild` would be a replacement for `dw`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `document.write` statement was already in an executing script tag, you could substitute it with:

```
var script = document.createElement('script')
script.src = src
var first = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]
first.parentNode.insertBefore(script, first)
```

Demo:

```js
// a delayed check to see if the script loaded
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(window.jQuery ? 'jQuery loaded!' : 'Uh oh!')
}, 5000)
```

```html
<script>
    var script = document.createElement('script')
    // example src
    script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'
    var first = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]
    first.parentNode.insertBefore(script, first)
</script>
```